# Escape slashes in capture groups in sed

Tags: jenkins, sed

I have the following code for getting an input (the second %s parameter
-- marisol in the example below) from Jenkins

```
'''sed -i -e 's/^\\(%s[ ]*=[ ]*\\)\\(.*\\)/\\1%s/' "%s/file/%s"'''
```

and it works for strings from letters and digits  - finds the `name` in file and puts `marisol` after `name =`

```
sed -i -e s/^\(name[ ]*=[ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1marisol/
```

But I also have a path input, like so

```
sed -i -e s/^\(document[ ]*=[ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1s3://bucket/folder/text.txt/
```

And with path input sed fails with unknown option to s error because of slashes which I have as delimiters.

I wanted to escape potential slashes in my input so that sed doesn't fail or turn them into `\/`, so that sed could take the path as `s3:\/\/bucket\/folder\/text.txt`

I know I can use another sed delimiter but I would also like to understand whether and how it is possible to manipulate input with capture groups and regex

Comment: I don't understand your question. And I'm not sure that I understand your current code snippet. Why do you have all those single quotes.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear @AndreasLouv Triple simple quotes are for not interfering with Groovy's special characters. For example my input is `s3://bucket/folder/text.txt` and I want to get it as `s3:\/\/bucket\/folder\/text.txt` or even better as is `s3://bucket/folder/text.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `/` as the substitute delimiter, then it's a special character and needs to be escaped yielding `\/` The backslash is already a meta character and needs to be escaped to be treated literally yielding `\\`. Putting it together:

```
s/\//\\\//g
```

will replace all slashes with `\/`.

It *will* be easier to read if you use another delimiter:

```
s:/:\\/:g
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Louv  Yes, but now sed doesn't accept my input with slashes (fails with unknown option for s error) as it has slash as the delimiter. I want to escape it for sed and get my input as is or with `\/`. Can I put `\\\/` in the second parenthesis (meaning get the input as `s3:\/\/bucket\/folder\/text.txt`) `'''sed -i -e 's/^\\(%s[ ]*=[ ]*\\)\\(.*\\\/\\)/\\1%s/' "%s/file/%s"'''`?

Comment: Make sure to put the sed command in single quotes, or the shell will interpreted the quotes: `sed 's/\//\\\//g'`

Comment: Yes, thank you @Andreas Louv But I'm starting to think it is impossible to implement what I wanted: first to escape slashes or turn them into `\/` and then do the actual replacement in file, because from what I read sed cannot do sequential replacements in one command

Comment: Just chain them together: `sed -e 's/a/b/g' -e 's/c/d/g'`

Comment: Just tried, thank you, but it still doesn't want to work  `+ sed -e s/\//\\\// -e s/^\(document[ ]*=[ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1s3://bucket/folder/text.txt/ -i /path/to/file.ini
sed: -e expression #2, char 43: unknown option to `s'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo "s3://bucket/folder/text.txt" | sed s'|\(/\)|\\\1|g'
s3:\/\/bucket\/folder\/text.txt
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you @HatLess maybe I can use multiple capturing groups -- to replace slashes in input first and make replacement in file afterwards

Comment: @Marisol I am a little confused, what replacements need to be made after? Can you clarify in your question and make it clearer what you are trying to achieve maybe with some before and after example data?